Aggregate query in MS Access
Is there a way to SELECT prevent duplicates when using the Sum function in MS Access?
I have tried:
SELECT StaffNo, StaffName, Sum([Pay]) As TotalPay 
FROM tblHours
WHERE tblHours.Restricted ='Yes'
GROUP BY StaffNo, StaffName;

But the results returns duplicate rows:
Edited:
tblHours

Expected:

Or is there any other methods for accomplishing this task?
Regards

Either "W001" or "Sam H" represents unique values. That why. So, double-check your data.

Your description does not match your sample data. Please provide sample data as text, not picture.

Your query is written to do exactly what you want. It's your data that is bad. There is likely some trailing white space (or something) in one of those entries. Like Sam H    or W001   that is making the value unique and causing your aggregation to fail.

Try this, "select distinct StaffNo, StaffName from tblHours order by Staffno" to see what you get for W001. If it is duplicated there, then there is some non-printable character or trailing space in those fields. What are the data types (The data is redundant, you are not using normalization, this problem would occur anytime)

Thoughts on trying to trim your non aggregate fields to see if that removes white space etc...?
SELECT trim(StaffNo) AS StaffNo, trim(StaffName) AS StaffName, Sum([Pay]) As TotalPay
FROM tblHours
WHERE tblHours.Restricted ='Yes'
GROUP BY TRIM(StaffNo), TRIM(StaffName);

@Gustav The data is correct the table has Auto primary key and accepts duplicate StaffNo. I have left out the Restricted Column in the sample image because it contains 'Yes' for all the records.

I see that there are many rows with Sam H. and Sam  H and Sam H. therefore giving me duplicates for W001 Is there a way around this?

@Fil clean your data and make sure such things cannot happen. Otherwise you'll always  get the problem "shit in, shit out"

Probably best to have a lookup staff table and join in on it with the staffno.

Agree with @VLOOKUP: tblHours should not have staff name, only staff ID. Join to Staff table where each person is unique. And maybe use autonumber field as key in Staff and join on that instead of StaffNo text field. Also, could build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs in textbox. This allows viewing detail data as well as summary calcs.

As I said before, it occurs because of redundant data. Read normalization at least up to 3rd Normal form.  In practice, in another table (say Staff) you should have StaffNo and StaffName, where StaffNo is unique. In this table you should only have StaffNo to link to Staff table.

In a properly designed relational database the relationship between StaffNo and StaffName is held in a separate table (called, say, tblStaff), where StaffNo is the primary key (or a unique key); then you would use a join to get that name. This design prevents the name to be repeated in multiple forms, like you have (search for database normalisation to learn more about this).
Ask yourself, of those with 'Sam H.' and 'Sam  H' and 'Sam H.' which one do you want to keep? if it doesn't matter you can 'make up ' a staff table by just taking one of them for each StaffNo, like this:
In this example, I use MIN to take just one value of StaffName: the one that comes first when they are alphabetically sorted) for each StaffNo. 
SELECT th.StaffNo, Staff.MinStaffName as StaffName, Sum([Pay]) As TotalPay 
FROM tblHours th
     inner join
     (select StaffNo, min(StaffName) as MinStaffName
      from tblHours ths
      group by StaffNo) as Staff
     on th.StaffNo=Staff.StaffNo
WHERE th.Restricted =Yes
GROUP BY th.StaffNo, Staff.MinStaffName


Supper! @Tinazmu, it's as though the 'min' function is the normalisation factor here. It seem to function flawlessly since 'StaffNo' is the identifier on the query results and no need to distinguish 'StaffName'. Cheers!
